# LibreOffice applications hides half of the Ubuntu dock

Tags: libreoffice, dock

From time to time, the Libreoffice applications like Writer and Calc and the ubuntu dock overlap with a transparency effect. This also happens with Evince (pdf reader). To solve this, you have to minimize the application window and then maximize it to see the dock correctly.

I don't experience this with other applications (except evince).

Is there a special setting to avoid this ?
Ubuntu 22.04 - LibreOffice 7.3.7.2

Comment: LO will usually remember that last opened setting. Use the corner of the application to resize it and you should be good to go next use.